# variables in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a following line in my shell script.

```
time mysqlshow -u$user -p$password |  egrep -v 'information_schema|performance_schema' | awk '{print "mysql -u$user -p$password -Bse \"drop database", $2, "\""}'
```

The first $user is correctly changing to username variable. But the one within awk statement does not. I tried to add double and single quotes with and without escape characters \ but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that `$user` and `$password` are surrounded by double quotes (`"`) or by nothing and, [as @jkerian mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695503/variables-in-awk/7695527#7695527#7695527), that `$2` is surrounded by single quotes (`'`) or, if it is in double quotes, preceded by a backslash to make `\$2`.

Try this (this is the cleaner one in my opinion):

```
time mysqlshow -u$user -p$password |
    egrep -v 'information_schema|performance_schema' |
    awk '{print "mysql -u'"$user"' -p'"$password"' -Bse \"drop database", $2, "\""}'
```

Or this:

```
time mysqlshow -u$user -p$password |
    egrep -v 'information_schema|performance_schema' |
    awk '{print "mysql -u'$user' -p'$password' -Bse \"drop database", $2, "\""}'
```

Or this:

```
time mysqlshow -u$user -p$password |
    egrep -v 'information_schema|performance_schema' |
    awk "{print \"mysql -u$user -p$password -Bse \\\"drop database\", \$2, \"\\\"\"}"
```

It's a mess, I know. But it should work.

Comment: You can use implement the egrep part in your awk script, too. `time mysqlshow -u$user -p$password | awk "!/information_schema|performance_schema/{print \"mysql -u$user -p$password -Bse \\\"drop database\", \$2, \"\\\"\"}"`

Answer (score 0):

That $2 needs to be handed down to awk without being interpreted by the shell.

Surround the $2 with single-quotes.